# How to update environment variable on the same session (immediately) on powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I would like to write some scripts on powershell, it involve using the environment variable on windows

here is the example of the script

test.ps1

```
setX number 456
echo $env:number
```

I found that $env:number cannot be updated immedately on the same session of powershell prompt. I need to reopen the powershell prompt. However, this would break my scripts
How can i update the env variable immedately? In linux it is easy to do with EXPORT command, but for windows, it is a hazard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerSell environment variables are available through a provider. A `provider` is a way to manupulation all kind of tree containers. have à look at :

```
Get-PSProvider
```

Then drives are entities using these providers. have a look at

```
Get-PSDrive
```

You can see that it exists a drive called `env`

You can try :

```
Get-childItem env:
```

to set an environment variables you can write :

$env:mavar = "TESTJPB"

To create more permanent environment variables (i.e., user-level or machine-level) you need to use the .NET Framework and the SetEnvironmentVariable method. For example, this command creates a user-level environment variable named TestVariable:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("mavar", "TESTJPB", "User")
```

Have a look to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx) Microsoft article.

Comment: After I set [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("mavar", "TESTJPB", "User"), it doesn't take effect on the same session of the same powershell. It only take effect on creating new powershell. How can i avoid?

Comment: `$env:mavar` = "TESTJPB" change it for local PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
[environment]::setenvironmentvariable()
```