# Subprocess $Env:Path python: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, windows, powershell, environment-variables, subprocess

I am trying to change the windows environment variables, but I am having trouble doing so.

Before I tried to use `os.environ()` I tried out using powershell commands and adding a string to `$Env:Path` which worked, but removing it with:

```
$env:Path = ($env:Path.Split(';') | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_ -ne $Remove}) -join ';'
```

however didn't seem to remove it being my path I want to add `("FFmpeg:C:\Users\user\AppData\"`) and adding it with `+= C:/Users/etc..` didn't see, the way to go.

Another way I tried to add vars through the Powershell commands was using [`SetEnviormentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2) and it seemed to work fine but once I restarted my PC the entry I made with it was gone.

Sadly though all in the end **all my powershell commands didn't work** with subprocess. Whatever command it was I was using here I got:

```
PS C:\Users\Me123> python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run("$Env:Path", shell=True)
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

CompletedProcess(args='$Env:Path', returncode=1)
```

Comment: I'm confused. When you tried `python main.py`, it looks like powershell couldn't find python.exe. If its a problem with a python `subprocess` module call, show that call. Those functions usually have an `env` parameter used to pass an alternate environment. If you want to add something to the path, do it there.

Comment: I think that the answer exists in [How to update environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950125/608772), you can use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("mavar", "TESTJPB", "User")`

Comment: @tdelaney Haha I forgot to maybe clarify I a bit more of what that codeblock meant. I updated it please look. I get this when subprocess calls the run function I guess to PS and I get this error/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `subprocess` on Windows does not call Powershell by default but CMD shell. So try the analogous CMD command:

```py
subprocess.run("echo %Path%", shell=True)
```

But if you need Powershell, explicitly call it with your command:

```py
subprocess.run("powershell $Env:Path", shell=True)
```

Comment: This is all completely unnecessary, though. Whatever is in your `PATH` is already visible in `os.environ["Path"]`

Comment: @tripleee, Correct. But OP may need to run a Powershell command beyond this simple output of `Path` like setting permanent environment variables.

Comment: The last weird way to do that would be to use the `env` keyword argument to `subprocess` to supply an updated environment to the subprocess.

Comment: @tripleee I am not sure what your talking about with `env` in subprocess

Comment: If you wanted to add `c:\poo` to your `PATH` while running `ffmpeg` in a subprocess, that would be `myenv = os.environ.copy(); myenv["PATH"] += r';c:\poo'; subprocess.run("ffmpeg", env=myenv)`